# Impedance reflection in making a simple current source

Tags: transistors, impedance, biasing

I am making a constant current source using the transistor. I am a bit confused regarding the biasing of the transistor. I have seen in many places that when we are setting the biasing of the transistor like I want 1 mA of current so I have to set up 1 V at the emitter. Thus I have to set up 1.7 V in case I am using a transistor with 0.7 VBE. Now after I simply choose the values of the resistors R1 and R2 I have to consider the impedance reflection that is making beta times RE in parallel with the R2.

Now I want to ask that will the R2 now reflect inside or not in this case? If I have to do it then the circuit will continue oscillating like RE reflecting R2 and then R2 reflecting RE?

Kindly help me.

[image]

Image source:  [Transistor as current source](https://www.planetanalog.com/an-analog-tutorial-current-sources/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I have to do it then the circuit will continue oscillating like RE reflecting R2 and then R2 reflecting RE???

Nothing is oscillating, but it does sound like your mind is going round in circles.

First important thing to note is that this is not a very accurate or constant current source, so it is pointless to try to do very accurate calculations. V<sub>BE</sub> varies with temperature, and the transistor beta could vary by a factor of 3, so all you can do is get somewhere in the right ballpark. If you want a really accurate or constant current source, then you would use an opamp to sense the voltage on Re, and drive TR1 base.

The worst case base current will be your load current divided by the minimum beta of TR1.

Now set the current through R1 and R2 to be much more than this, most people aim for a factor of 10 times larger.

As the base current loads the R1/R2 divider, you would expect the output current to be a bit lower than what you want. You could compute the output impedance of R1 and R2, and tweak the voltage up a bit. However, with a higher beta transistor, the loading will be less, and so the Re voltage will increase. As the temperature varies, the V<sub>BE</sub> will change, so changing the V across Re and so the current.

I've not dealt with Re being reflected onto the base through beta, because it's not relevant in this application. It is appropriate for small signals, a small change in base and emitter voltages. Here, we are dealing with absolute voltages, and it's better to simply compute the currents and the expected voltage drops associated with each.

Comment: I ve seen the emiiter resistor times beta taken in parallel with the input resistance R2 which creates a less change to the resistance. But does the same happen at the emitter end R2/beta+1 or at the emiiter end this is not reflected?

Comment: @MohammadHamza It's likely you've seen that in the context of small signal analysis. This is not a 'small signal' circuit.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit won't oscillate. There is no feedback mechanism. It will just settle to a constant current through the load. This circuit and similar ones are in use in innumerable different devices without any problems.
The usual design technique is to set the current through R1 & R2 so that it is at least 10 times Ib so that Ib becomes insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

To solve an equation numerically you may have to *iterate*, but that does not mean that anything physical is going on like oscillation. Since the effect of Re on base voltage is typically small (by design), you don't need to iterate many times to get something very close to the exact (theoretical) value. This is common with numerical (as opposed to closed form) solutions to equations.

If you don't want to iterate you can write equations and maybe you can solve them.

In this case it's pretty easy- replace R1 and R2 with Rt and Vt (Thevenin equivalents)

Then we have Vb = Vt - Ib*Rt  and Ib = (Vb-0.7)/(Re * (beta+1)), which is easily solved for Vb

\$V_b =\frac{V_T + \frac{0.7R_t}{R_e\beta'}}{\frac{R_t}{R_e\beta'}+1} \$ where \$\beta' = \beta+1\$

So as \$\beta'\$ goes to \$\infty\$ Vb goes to Vt, as expected.

Simplify by introducing the dimensionless term \$\alpha =   R_t/\beta'R_e \$:

\$V_t = V_b + \alpha(V_b- 0.7)\$

So suppose \$\alpha\$ = 0.1 then for Vb = 1.7V we have Vt = 1.8V.  We pick the number 0.1 to keep the current relatively independent of beta, while not wasting too much current through the divider.

Since Vbe changes with temperature, and there are other effects such as Early voltage, there's little real improvement in reducing \$\alpha\$ much beyond that point.

---

A similar but simpler situation could be if I wanted to calculate the resistance required to get (say) 500mV from a 5V source and with a 1kΩ series resistor. If I approximate the current as 5mA, the required resistor would be 100Ω. Of course the current won't be 5mA any longer with the 100Ω resistor in series (calculate it as 4.54mA) and then the resistor becomes 110Ω. Now the current is 4.505mA and the resistor becomes 111Ω and we're already within 0.1%.

But if we just solved the equation (trivial in this case) we would have found the ideal resistor value to be 111.111Ω (repeating decimal).